# ASP.Net-VB to .MDF connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to update my database using VB in my .net application. I have added a data_Set file in my app_code folder and uploaded my database to it. I cant seem to update the table and insert new rows to it. (I am new to database) The database file is .mdf and I followed the instructions for data access layers (generated sql statements).

here is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CreatePatient.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CreatePatientConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CreatePatient.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here is my VB:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ErrorTXT.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Protected Sub SignUp_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SignUp.Click

        Dim CCSQL As New SqlConnection
        Dim CCUser As New SqlCommand
        Dim strSQL As String
        If IsValid Then
            Try
                CCSQL.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CreatePatientConnectionString").ConnectionString
                strSQL = "insert into CreatePatient  (Account, Password, FirstName, LastName, Address, HomePhone, Mobile, City, State, Zip, Social, Age, Gender, Height, Weight, Marital, Spouse) values (@Account, @Password, @FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @HomePhone, @Mobile, @City, @State, @Zip, @Social, @Age, @Gender, @Height, @Weight, @Marital, @Spouse)"
                CCUser.CommandText = strSQL
                CCUser.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Account", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Account.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Password", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstName.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@LastName", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LastName.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Address", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Address.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@HomePhone", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = HomePhone.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Mobile.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@City", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = City.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@State", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = State.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Zip", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = ZipCode.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Social", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SSN.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Age", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CurrentAge.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Gender", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Gender.SelectedValue
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Height", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Height.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Weight", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Weight.Text
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Marital", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Marital.SelectedValue
                CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Spouse", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Spouse.Text
                CCSQL.Open()
                CCUser.Connection = CCSQL
                Response.Redirect("ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx")
                CCSQL.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                ErrorTXT.Text = ex.Message
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The idea is to fill out the account credentials and store them in the database. Let me know if I am missing any information. I am new to stackoverflow, ASP.net, and SQL so ty for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is missing of the call to [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) that inserts the data in your database

```
If IsValid Then
    Try
        Dim strSQL = "insert into CreatePatient  (Account, Password, FirstName, LastName, " & _
                 "Address, HomePhone, Mobile, City, State, Zip, Social, Age, Gender, " & _
                 "Height, Weight, Marital, Spouse) values (@Account, @Password, @FirstName, " & _
                 "@LastName, @Address, @HomePhone, @Mobile, @City, @State, @Zip, @Social, " & _
                 "@Age, @Gender, @Height, @Weight, @Marital, @Spouse)"
        Using CCSQL = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CreatePatientConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using CCUser = new SqlCommand(strSQL, CCSQL)
            CCSQL.Open()
            CCUser.Parameters.Add("@Account", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Account.Text
            ......
            CCUser.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect("ProcedureSelectionForm.aspx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorTXT.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End If
```

I have also enclosed the creation of the `SqlConnection` and the `SqlCommand` in a [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) that ensures the proper closing and disposing of the connection and the command also in case of Exceptions